# Is there a way to squeeze range by certain ratio?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

On a huge dataset `std::ranges::equal_range` returns very large range. Due to performance considerations in such a case I want to process not all the elements in the resulting range but evenly distributed `in_range_i_need_only` elements; like I am taking only `n`th element where n approximately  `range.size()/number of elements` (this can be linear ratio with division, Bresenham ratio); doesn’t matter.

Is there a way to easy modify the range (with views, etc.) to the range which consist of evenly distributed `in_range_i_need_only` elements?

I am looking into [slide_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/slide_view) or [chunk_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/chunk_view), but they produce subranges and I need to modify my range since after that it goes to `std::ranges::for_each`.

Is there some straightforward way to do so?

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

float gen()
{
    static float v=0.0f;
    v+=0.1f;
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t some_huge_size=100;
    std::vector<float> values(some_huge_size);

    std::ranges::generate(values, gen);

    const int some_value_to_search = some_huge_size/10-1;
    auto range = std::ranges::equal_range(values,some_value_to_search,{},[](auto& v){ return int(v); });

    const int in_range_i_need_only = 4;
    std::ranges::for_each(range, [](auto& v) { std::cout << v << ", ";});
}
```

See the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6oxrnPv61)

The expected result for this case would be something like (extra spaced added for readability):

> 9.1, 9.3, 9.5, 9.7,

Comment: Why not use a standard `for (..; ..; in_range_i_need_only += 4) { ... }`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I want to stay with ranges and advances they give (up to lazy calculations, etc. and don't want to move to usual iterators which will be needed in case of for. At the moment I use similar implementation, but (1) you are wrong (I guess misprint) with in_range_i_need_only += 4, we should have something like it+= values.size()/(in_range_i_need_only+1), still having issues with bounding conditions and (2) in case in_range_i_need_only  close to values.size() only floating point math would work (see my comment under answer from *Artyer* below.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, and the key is that the code in a way *Artyer* showed is concise and easy to support, since it much shorter. When one gets accustomed to ranges/views/projections, it is very hard to give them up.

Comment: No worries, just a suggestion until someone had a concise answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`views::stride`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/stride_view):

```cpp
std::ranges::for_each(range | std::ranges::views::stride(range.size() / in_range_i_need_only), [](auto& v) { std::cout << v << " ";});
// 9.1 9.3 9.5 9.7 9.9
```

This actually prints one more than needed, but that can be fixed by a `| views::take(in_range_i_need_only)`

Comment: Thank you! One small reservation, feel free to update your answer with it, if you like. When the `in_range_i_need_only` value is close to the number of elements in the range (larger than a half of it; let's say, I need 7 out of 10), it puts the numbers too close to each other because of the integer division. See the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GoEcrcnYq); it provides 9 numbers instead of 7 and if I use `take`, the values in the end part of the range won't be represented at all. Anyway, this is precisely what I was looking for. The only issue to aware is this integer division.